# Pipe multiple jq values to "while read -r" loop

Tags: json, bash, while-loop, jq, ifs

I am trying to find a clean way to assign 2 json string values to 2 variables within a while loop. The loop and input I am working with are as follows.

INPUT:

```
foo='
[
   {
      "name":"name string (more info)",
      "nested_name":{
         "name":"my name",
         "conclusion":"failure",
         "number":11
      }
   },
   {
      "name":"name string (more info)",
      "nested_name":{
         "name":"my other name",
         "conclusion":"failure",
         "number":13
      }
   }
]'
```

Currently I have the following:

```
echo "$foo" | jq ".[].name,.[].nested_name.name" | while read -r foo bar; do
    # do stuff with foo and bar
done
```

In iteration 1, I want:

```
foo = "name string (more info)" 
bar = "my name"
```

Iteration 2:

```
foo = "name string (more info)" 
bar = "my other name"
```

However this generates the following incorrect output:

```
foo = "name 
bar = string (more info)"
foo = "name 
bar = string (more info)"
foo = "my 
bar = name"
foo = "my 
bar = other name"
```

I've been at this all day, any input or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use two `read`s, one for each line:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

json='
[
   {
      "name":"name string (more info)",
      "nested_name":{
         "name":"my name",
         "conclusion":"failure",
         "number":11
      }
   },
   {
      "name":"name string (more info)",
      "nested_name":{
         "name":"my other name",
         "conclusion":"failure",
         "number":13
      }
   }
]'


while read -r foo && read -r bar; do
    printf "foo=%s\nbar=%s\n" "$foo" "$bar"
done < <(jq ".[] | .name, .nested_name.name" <<<"$json")
```

---

I had to change your `jq` expression to get your desired output.

Also note using different names for your original JSON text and the loop variable, using a [*here string*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) instead of `echo`, and using file redirection instead of a pipeline; useful if the body of the `while` sets any variables needed later.

---

An alternative that reads all the `jq` output into an array and then iterates it:

```sh
readarray -t lines < <(jq ".[] | .name, .nested_name.name" <<<"$json")
for (( i = 0; i < ${#lines[@]}; i += 2 )); do
    foo=${lines[i]}
    bar=${lines[i+1]}
    printf "foo=%s\nbar=%s\n" "$foo" "$bar"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! I combined your answer with another persons to get the exact behavior I needed. First time posting on here and I am blown away with the quality and timeliness of the responses, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I simulate some "CSV input" I can do this: (Note the `IFS` set to `,`)

```sh
echo 'aaa,bbb\nccc,ddd' | while IFS=, read -r x y; do
  echo "x=$x, y=$y"
done
```

Output:

```
x=aaa, y=bbb
x=ccc, y=ddd
```

You can generate a similar "CSV output" with the following `jq` command:

```
jq --raw-output '.[] | "\(.name),\(.nested_name.name)"'
```

So I think it'd look something like this:

```sh
echo "$foo" | jq --raw-output '.[] | "\(.name),\(.nested_name.name)"' | while IFS=, read -r foo bar; do
    # do stuff with foo and bar
done
```

Comment: What if there's a comma in one of the name strings?

Comment: @Shawn Yep fair. I expected that comment ;) That wouldn't work in this case indeed. If there's no chance for it to happen then it may or may not be a decent workaround.

Answer (score 0):

how about this: https://jqplay.org/s/4MPWmMjFmM

```
assuming foobar.json
    jq -r '.[] | "foo=\"" + .name + "\"","bar=\"" + .nested_name.name + "\""' foobar.json
    foo="name string (more info)"
    bar="my name"
    foo="name string (more info)"
    bar="my other name"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I piped this to a while -r loop using another persons answer and got exactly what I needed! First time posting a question on here and I am blown away :)

Comment: The thing with the comma is that, it does a new run on the data each time and pastes them all together like so: https://jqplay.org/s/mL_23Tl6Tr

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it like this:

```
jq --argjson foo "$foo" --null-input --compact-output '$foo[]' | while IFS= read -r item
do
    name="$(jq --argjson item "$item" --null-input --raw-output '$item.name')"
    nested_name="$(jq --argjson item "$item" --null-input --raw-output '$item.nested_name.name')"
    printf 'name is "%s" and nested_name is "%s"\n' "$name" "$nested_name"
done
```

While this method involves extra calls to `jq`, it has several benefits:

- It's easy to extend if you need to iterate over something with more complex structure.
- It's safe against spaces, commas, quotes, tabs and newlines.
- It's easy to understand and have confidence in. It doesn't involve any special algorithm, parsing or escaping.

Here's the same thing using abbreviated options if you want it a little bit more terse.

```
jq --argjson foo "$foo" -nc '$foo[]' | while IFS= read -r item
do
    name="$(jq --argjson item "$item" -nr '$item.name')"
    nested_name="$(jq --argjson item "$item" -nr '$item.nested_name.name')"
    printf 'name is "%s" and nested_name is "%s"\n' "$name" "$nested_name"
done
```

In a little more detail:

- We use `--argjson` to pass our JSON string in as a single argument and `--null-input` to ignore stdin. This way we don't have to worry about escaping or delimiters on the way in.
- We use `--compact-output` (or `-c`) to output one JSON object per line.
- We use `IFS=` to make sure that spaces and tabs inside our JSON string don't get picked up as delimiters. Only newlines will act as delimiters, and because all newlines inside JSON strings must be escaped, we can be confident that we will loop exactly once with for each item in the original JSON array.
- We use `--raw-output` (or `-r`) to output the value of the JSON string directly into the shell variable. (We can choose to omit this if we instead want the JSON-encoded string.)